# Do not show title text upon hover on input element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, html-input

I'm using jQuery Validate plugin and store Error messages in title, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="required email" title="Bad email format" />
```

I don't want the title text "Bad email format" to be shown upon hover. How can I disable this function (if it's possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use  `rel="Bad email format"` insted title or html data attributes like `data-errorMssg="Bad email format"` if you cant use them here is an extracted code to hide the title

```
(function($){  
 $.fn.hide_my_tooltips = function() {  


    return this.each(function() {  

        $(this).hover(function(e) {  
            // mouseover
            var $this=$(this);
            $this.data("myTitle",$this.attr("title")); //store title 
            $this.attr("title",""); 
            }, function() {  
            // mouseout
            var $this=$(this);

            $this.attr("title",$this.data("myTitle")); //add back title
        });

        $(this).click(function() {  
            var $this=$(this);
            $this.attr("title",$this.data("myTitle")); //add back title
        });
    });  
 };  
})(jQuery);
```

// in document ready function call the JQ function with correct selectors.
    $("input").hide_my_tooltips();

​

Comment: Thanks, this function is working, "rel" and "data-Msg" were not working

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the error message somewhere else. For example in a JavaScript array:

```
var errors = { "emailformat" : "Bad email format" }
```

And do with it whenever you need it, call it from the array instead of from html.

Comment: Can you please specify how I can use this with jQuery Validation plugin? Do I have to add special rule for each input element?